# Can't crawl Excel 2003 files from SharePoint 2013

Tags: excel, ifilter

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm and am crawling the contents of a legacy SharePoint 2007 farm on the same network domain.

I am getting the following error crawling Excel 2003 files (i.e. xls format) from the SharePoint 2007 farm:

> The file is in an unsupported version. ( Error parsing document 'http://siteurl/myexcelfile.xls'. Error loading IFilter for extension '.xls' (Error code is 0x8004170C). The document format is not recognized by the filter.; ; SearchID = 60699FAA-4C5C-422A-BE50-6464581D4EB1 )

The .xls file type is listed as an included file type in SharePoint 2013, so I am presuming the IFilter is in place.

My understanding is that the IFilter automatically comes with SharePoint 2013.

Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Hi did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, sort of.  I logged it with Microsoft and they accepted it as a bug whereby SharePoint 2013 doesn't recognize the Office 2003 binary file formats (e.g. xls, doc, ppt) when crawling files.  A clumsy workaround is to download the affected files, make a small change to the file in Office 2010 to force the internal file format to be updated, and then re-upload them to our SharePoint 2013 farm.   After I did that, the files were crawled successfully.  Not pretty, especially if you have hundreds or thousands of files.

Ian